# Splitting list into lists of a maximal length

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

For instance 
I want to make a list which has 20 numbers showed below. separate

```
(list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
      11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20)
```

into list of list which contains 10 numbers in each list. just like below

```
(list (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
      (list 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20))
```

what is the best way to do this?

//Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```scm
(define (take n xs)
   (if (or (= n 0)
           (null? xs) )
      '()
      (cons (car xs)
            (take (- n 1)
                  (cdr xs) ))))

(define (drop n xs)
   (if (or (= n 0)
           (null? xs) )
      xs
      (drop (- n 1)
            (cdr xs) )))

(define (split n xs)
   (if (null? xs) '()
      (cons (take n xs)
            (split n (drop n xs)) )))


(display
   (split 3 (list 1 2 3 4 5)) )    ; `((1 2 3) (4 5))`
```

Alternative `split` definition, elimination of wrapper recursion using named let:

```scm
(define (split n xs)
   (let spl ((xs' xs))    ; Named let
      (if (null? xs') '()
         (cons (take n xs')
               (spl (drop n xs')) ))))
```

Comment: Thnak you. help a lot